# Add the same child shape to multiple objects

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, shapes

Ok so I have this vector shape:

```
        my_shape.graphics.lineStyle(1, 0x00FF00, 1);
        my_shape.graphics.moveTo(30, 38);
        my_shape.graphics.lineTo(7, 38);
        my_shape.graphics.curveTo(-1, 38, -1, 36);
        my_shape.graphics.lineTo(-1, 3);
        my_shape.graphics.curveTo(-1, -1, 3, -1);
        my_shape.graphics.lineTo(35, -1);
        my_shape.graphics.curveTo(39, -1, 39, 3);
        my_shape.graphics.lineTo(39, 30);
```

1. Since I couldn't find how can I change color of the existing shape I created 3 of these with only difference in the color,is it possible to change color of the existing shape?
2. Is it possible to use that same shape in other classes? Or I have to create it again?
3. `if(ability3.Locked == true && Ability.suma >= 5){
               ability3.Locked = false;
               ability3.addChild(my_shape);
               ability4.Locked = false;
               ability4.addChild(my_shapea);
               ability5.Locked = false;
               ability5.addChild(my_shapeb);
           }
           if(ability6.Locked == true && Ability.suma >= 10){
               ability6.Locked = false;
               ability6.addChild(my_shapeb);
               ability7.Locked = false;
               ability7.addChild(my_shapea);
               ability8.Locked = false;
               ability8.addChild(my_shape);
               ability9.Locked = false;
               ability9.addChild(my_shape);
           }`

When this first code (ability 3 to 5) runs all 3 childs show but when it comes to running other if command abilities 6 to 9 get their children but 3 to 5 got their removed..can i use multiple times the same shape?

I hope you understand what I meant xD
Thanks.

Comment: The graphics class has a `copyFrom` method. You can easily change color with the `colorTransform` object. I'll post a code example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of copying graphics from one object to another, and changing their color:

```
var newShape:Shape = new Shape();
newShape.graphics.copyFrom(my_shape.graphics);

var colorTrans:ColorTransform = new ColorTransform();
colorTrans.color = 0xFFFFFF;
newShape.transform.colorTransform = colorTrans;
```

Answer (score 1):

A display object can only be on a single display list at a time. This means that if I do the following:

`container1.addChild(my_shape);
container2.addChild(my_shape);`

`my_shape` will end up on `container2`

Normally, you would create a class for this particular shape and instantiate it as needed, but judging from your code, I'm not sure that you're using OOP (please correct me if I'm wrong and I'll update my answer).

Having said that, you can always write a function that creates the shape you need using the color of your choosing:

```
function createShape(color:uint):Shape
{
    var shape:Shape = new Shape();

    shape.graphics.lineStyle(1, color, 1);
    shape.graphics.moveTo(30, 38);
    shape.graphics.lineTo(7, 38);
    shape.graphics.curveTo(-1, 38, -1, 36);
    shape.graphics.lineTo(-1, 3);
    shape.graphics.curveTo(-1, -1, 3, -1);
    shape.graphics.lineTo(35, -1);
    shape.graphics.curveTo(39, -1, 39, 3);
    shape.graphics.lineTo(39, 30);

    return shape;
}
```

Now you can call that function whenever you need to create the shape:

```
    if(ability3.Locked == true && Ability.suma >= 5){
        ability3.Locked = false;
        ability3.addChild(createShape(someColor));
        ability4.Locked = false;
        ability4.addChild(createShape(someOtherColor));
        ability5.Locked = false;
        ability5.addChild(createShape(anotherColor));
    }
```

Where `someColor`, `someOtherColor`, and `anotherColor` each represent a different `uint` (color).

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thanks. I wanted to create same script for something else in witch case I need a name of these shapes so I can use them separately. Is there a way to make the shape somehow like this: 'addChild(createShape(name_of_the_shape,color));'?

Comment: Looks like you already got your answer, but the way you would accomplish that with the example above would be simply to assign the results of `createShape` to a variable: `var shape:Shape = createShape(color);`